# Walking-Driving area with Leaflet,OpenLayers

Tags: postgis, sql

Could be possible to get a walking or driving distance area using pgr_drivindistance,pgr_alphashape and/or pgr_pointsaspolygon when an user click any location  on map with Leaflet or OpenLayers?.

I am new programming in sql and trying to get the correct result I found the first problem on how to pass source node which is integer to double ( x , y).

The second one is how to join pgr_drivindistance and pgr_alphashape so that through Geoserver get the walking-driving polygon when the user clicks(x,y) on the map.

Would have another chance to achieve that objective with another functions?.

Answer (score 1):

Just use Geoserver SQL views 
http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/adding_data/add_sqllayers.html

http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/geoserver.html

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/adding_data/add_sqllayers.html give me an idea on how to get work two function in one unic calls.

Comment: Your welcome.here also an article.I think it was written whis pgrouting 1.x but you still get an idea: https://wiki.smu.edu.sg/1112t2is415g1/images/0/04/Report_v2.pdf

Comment: This article is a good reference and a approximation to the final target. The link http://anitagraser.com/2011/05/13/catchment-areas-with-pgrouting-driving_distance/ is one of the steps that i have followed but i don't know if could be possible to change the start_id::int4 to ::double format to admit (%x% %y%).I will try.


Respect to pass source node(int) as variable(x,y),double,  it is better to develop a new pgr_drivedistance function changing the format to this parameters?

Comment: Yes.write a wrapper-function.here you find more details: http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/wrapper.html. there they write a function pgr_fromAtoB with two coordinates as input parameter which they use to find the nearest nodes to this coordinates. you can adapt this for your needs so you pass just one coordinate and for example the distance value